# How do I set the parameters in the auditd.conf file when deploying a tool?

Tags: linux, deployment, configuration

I am trying to deploy a tool, but have to set one of the parameters in the **auditd.conf** file to a different value.  Namely, I have to set **action_mail_acct** to **d_bailey@co.com** rather than **root**.  Is there a way to do that in the **bootstrap.sh** or other files during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to do this:

```
$ sed s/"action_mail_acct = root"/"action_mail_acct = d_bailey@co.com"/g auditd.conf > auditd.temp
$ mv -f auditd.temp auditd.conf
```

Seems roudabout, but it works, at least at the command line level. I am open to better ideas.